# Tessellation in Teradata is deprecated, but Geoserver expects it to improve spatial query?

Tags: geoserver, wms, teradata

In the project am involved with, I am responsible to:

- store geospatial data in Teradata database
- join the geometry with other non-geospatial attributes in the database
- publish them with GeoServer with WMS

All the above requirements are passed actually. However the performance of WMS is noticeably slow, much slower than PostGIS-backed Geoserver.

So I dug into GeoServer log to see what happen behind the screen during WMS request, and i found several lines similar to the below:

> 2018-01-23 11:47:22,402 INFO [data.teradata] - Tessellation info not
>   available for GEOM, unable to perform spatially indexed query

It seems that the performance is slow because i did not setup Tessellation in Teradata database.

Well, I did not setup Tessellation because it is deprecated. Teradata documentation titled *Teradata Database SQL Geospatial Types 14.10, April 2014*, (PDF) page 4, says that since the version 14.10 *Native indexing (NUSIs) for geospatial data replaces tessellation as the preferred method for improving geospatial performance. Tessellation is deprecated.*

So there's something funny here:
Teradata document says that Tessellation is not the prefered method for improving performance, therefore is deprecated; but GeoServer expects Tessellation for spatial index.

Can anyone explain this? Or do i simply set Tessellation anyway?

The ecosystem used is:

- Teradata Database 16.00.00.14 on quite big machine.
- GeoServer 2.10.1 on JBOSS EAP 6 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code history the last actual code change is from 2013. The Teradata store has been donated by a developer years ago, he then left and the store has seen no core changes since, so it's not surprising the data source evolved away from the store implementation.

Connectors to proprietary data sources are typically maintained/improved on only during working hours, so I'd recommend to check commercial support: http://geoserver.org/support/

Answer (score 0):

I just happened on this thread and can give you a definitive (albeit belated) response.  I wrote the original Teradata datasource adapter for GeoServer.  It's true the implementation has not been updated recently.  There are a few tweaks to the adapter that could be made to more efficiently handle the retrieval of geospatial CLOB data to exploit improvements that have since been made on the database side. Having said that, it is still possible to take advantage of some of those improvements through settings of parameters on more recent versions of the JDBC driver (i.e., see settings for SLOB_RECEIVE_THRESHOLD and SLOB_TRANSMIT_THRESHOLD.) It is also true that while the latest documentation states that tessellation is deprecated, it has not and will not be going away.  It will continue to be supported.  The newer RTree-based spatial indexing is preferred in many cases from both an ease-of-use and performance perspective but there are still many cases where the degree of customization afforded by tessellation can be exploited to outperform RTree.

Comment: Hi there, very good to see someone that has knowledge of the code. We are slowly cleaning away modules that lack a maintainer, the jdbc-teradata one is going to be considered for that move. If it happens, the module will be moved in "unsupported" and removed from the GeoServer releases. If it's important to you, please chime in on the geotools developers list.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to point out that there are no special settings on the GeoServer datasource adapter for Teradata that are necessary to support the retrieval of spatial data that employs RTree spatial indexing.  It is also possible to use a combination of RTree and tessellation indexing in ways that maximize performance.  If RTree indexing is present, it will always be used transparently in the queries issued against Teradata.  As you know, the use of tessellation requires some additional settings on the Teradata datasource adapter.