# Teradata Store in Geoserver does not yet recognize Teradata Simplify method

Tags: geoserver, wms, teradata

In my previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/268871/18383) i asked why Geoserver WMS on Teradata is noticeably slow. I looked into Geoserver log and it appears that: GeoServer expects Tessellation for spatial index while Tessellation method is deprecated.

Andrea Aime describes that this is because the code for connection to Teradata store is from 2013 and not kept up with current Teradata implementation.

Now i have another curiosity:

the other reason Teradata-backed GeoServer WMS is slow (well at least compared with default-settings PostGIS) is because GeoServer connection to Teradata does not recognize Teradata newly-implemented *SimplifyPreserveTopology* method (implemented on March 2014 on Teradata DB version 15.00).

Can anyone confirm the above understanding?

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer can use PostGIS with an an-the-fly simplification by adding ST_Simplify() function into the database queries. This usually does make queries a little bit faster but may also lead to some issues [Small features don't draw when zoomed out using Geoserver WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/small-features-dont-draw-when-zoomed-out-using-geoserver-wms).

If you have PostGIS available with the same data you can make your own test between Teradata and PostGIS by turning the on-the-fly simplification off from PostGIS settings. Then simplification has no role and if Teradata store is still slower the reason is in some other place.

Comment: Also mind, ST_Simplify is fast because it's not topology preserving, tests done with the postgis topology preserving function showed no improvement (too high CPU cost to run it)